# OMNeT++ Configuration File

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I am implementing a VANET routing protocol using OMNeT++ (INET Framework), sumo and veins (to generate traffic).

Is it possible to add a configuration in the `omnetpp.ini`  to run the simulation with no vehicles in order to test an application for the RSUs?

Comment: You can use a second configuration where the ``.rou.xml``is empty. You can select the correct file from the ``omnetpp.ini``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want any traffic in your simulation you will have to modify the `.rou.xml` file which is used for your simulation.

In your example directory you probably have a file with such an extension, simply comment out the code. Or leave only two vehicles as it is in this case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/routes_file.xsd">

  <vType accel="5.0" decel="5.0" id="Car" length="5.0" minGap="2.0" maxSpeed="50.0" sigma="0" />

  <route id="route0" edges="1to2 out" />

  <vehicle depart="1" id="veh0" route="route0" type="Car" />
  <vehicle depart="1" id="veh1" route="route0" type="Car" />
</routes>
```

On the other hand it is a bit weird to me how would you test the application of the RSU if there are no cars. Meaning there is no transmission, meaning the RSU application reacts to what?

For a minimal example maybe you should use only one car in your scenario which sends a packet to the RSU.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is very helpful! Yes you are right, it makes more sense to test with one car and add more cars gradually.